# Radial gradient in shape of ring in HTML

Tags: html, css

Looking For help.

[image]

can anyone Please help me how to Create "Radial Bubble Effect gradient in shape of ring With Text" in Html

I am New Here, Please Help

I am Trying To Create Radial Bubble Effect gradient in shape of ring With Text" in Html/ CSS

Edit

```
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #49aeff, #ff4c89);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle i {
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #49aeff, #ff4c89);
  z-index: 2;
  inset: -5px;
  filter: blur(50px);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle i:nth-child(4) {
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 3;
  inset: 5px;
}

.circle j {
  position: absolute;
  inset: -5px;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  inset: 20px 20px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

**My Main Question** : Is This Possible To Create This Same Effect Without Using "**nth-child**" in CSS

Comment: What have you tried? We are here to help you with your problems, not to give full solutions from scratch.

Comment: I am New here, Sorry i didn't Write Everything in Question.
<style>
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #49aeff, #ff4c89);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


.circle i:nth-child(4) {
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 3;
  inset: 5px;
}

</style>  


My main Question is Is this Possible To Create This Same Effect Without Using "nth-child" in css

Comment: Please put your code into your question see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.circle{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position:relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, #fff 40%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
}
.circle p{
   text-align: center;
}
.circle:before {
    content: "";
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background:#fff linear-gradient(90deg, #ff3d00 0%, #0400ff 100% );
    mask-image: url(https://mdn.github.io/css-examples/masking/star.svg);
    filter: blur(20px);
    opacity: .3;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    border-radius: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
    <p>BUBBLE</p>
    <p>DESIGN</p>
    <p>HTML</p>
</div>
```

what I did is use the `:before` as the gradient and blur it. And set the background of the circle as `radial-gradient`. White background gradient start fade into transparent 40% from the center.

if you like the circle edge to be sharp edge. you can remove the `radial-gradient` and put a solid background.